# Выбор из базы записей у которых нет некоторых значений

Tags: php, mysql

Есть mySQL таблица в которой хранятся ссылки на видео добавленные в пост

```
id | post_id | host    | link 
1  | 15      | youtube | youtube.com
2  | 15      | vimeo   | vimeo.com
3  | 20      | youtube | youtube.com
4  | 20      | youtube | youtube.com
6  | 34      | vimeo   | vimeo.com
6  | 35      | vimeo   | vimeo.com
6  | 36      | youtube | youtube.com
```

Подскажите как составить запрос что бы выбрать из базы ID постов которые не имеют ссылки на youtube? В данном примере должно быть выбрано post_id 34 и 35

Сейчас я выбираю все записи и на PHP отсеиваю не нужные, но это на мой взгляд не очень верно, так как думаю что можно сразу выбирать нужные.

Comment: добавьте в ваш запрос примерно такое условие: WHERE link != 'youtube.com'

Comment: Это было бы очень просто. link я сократил так ка не давало опубликовать, там хранятся полные ссылки на ролики

Comment: ну тогда можно добавить в запрос такое условие: `WHERE link NOT LIKE '%youtube.com%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM <table>
WHERE post_id
NOT IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM <table>
    WHERE host = 'youtube'
)
```

– вместо `<table>` имя вашей таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

```
select post_id
  from Table
 group by post_id
 having sum(link='youtube.com')=0
```